# Sparkline Printing to PDF

Tags: pdf, export, sparklines

I have an issue where when I export to PDF via VBA my sparkline graphs are not printed.  I've browsed your site, and a few others, trying to come up with a solution.  Unfortunately I can't get it to work.

I'm the only one that uses the application, so the process is completely visible.  I've tried to do all of the following before the export line in an effort to get the sparklines to 'refresh':

1. application.screenupdating = false then application.screenupdating = true
2. application.visible = true (based on forum here, even though it was never hidden)
3. select the cell where sparkline is located
4. select entire sheet where sparkline(s) are located
5. select.copy the cell where sparkline is located
6. application.wait to see if it would refresh
7. application.calculate to see if it would refresh

I really can't think of anything else to try.  The spreadsheet is designed to create a report for a single entity, print the report, and then move on to create the next report for a different entity (pulls data from Access, creates over 200 10 page reports).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks - Kris.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I tried all of your listed ideas as well as `DoEvents`, but after testing the code line for line I found the offending code was:

```
.Axes.Vertical.MinScaleType = xlSparkScaleGroup
```

For some reason the `xlSparkScaleGroup` interferred with the update of the sparklines on the page and when I tried to update-print-update-print--- the sheet the sparklines were missing.  My solution was to simply remove this code and then manually set the scales.  Something like this:

```
.Axes.Vertical.MinScaleType = xlSparkScaleCustom

.Axes.Vertical.CustomMinScaleValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(SLAddress))

.Axes.Vertical.MaxScaleType = xlSparkScaleCustom

.Axes.Vertical.CustomMaxScaleValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(SLAddress))
```

where `SLAddress` was the address of the sparkline data I was using.  I hope this helps solve your issue and maybe Microsoft will actually fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had to use a temp file to make it happen.  Basically saved the current file as a temp file using 'savecopyas', then open the temp file (which allowed it to refresh the sparklines) do the print, close the temp file, and then start the process over again.

Hope they fix this at some point.

Kris.